# Title Alignment in Sliver SpaceFlexibleBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

Im very desperate. Im new to flutter and following the tutorials in YT. There I came across following problem and wonder how Im the only on.

In the YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY-_yrZdjGc&list=PLjxrf2q8roU3wk7CDw4RfV3mEwOJbjx1k&index=5) video one gets explained how to use sliver. I great tool for scrolling experiences I guess.

But after following the tutorial and even visiting the solution on flutter.dev/go/sliver-workshop I cant get to allign the title in the center.

Code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djjw0.png)

Picture:
[Horizons not alligned in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWiTx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to debug such layout behaviour is to make use of the built-in [`Widget Inspector`](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector).

I have ran the codelab's code in an iOS simulator and enabled the overlay guidelines. You can see in the below screenshot that the title is actually centered. However, there are some padding in the left and bottom.

You could also try to replace `title: const Text('Horizons'),` with `title: const Placeholder(),` which will also show you the layout.

So the answer to your question is: there is [default padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar/titlePadding.html) for `FlexibleSpaceBar` and adding the below line should fix it.

`titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,`

[image: demo]

Comment: Hello Im new to stack overflow so Im not sure if comments should be used this way. But I just want to thank you very much for solving my problem and taking the time to write so detailed about it! To be honest I didnt expect an answer so soon and certainly not one so insightful. I have to definetly read into Widget Inspector thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Simply saying thank you in comments is not encouraged. You may check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I think yours is fine and I really appreciate it.